One-dimensional Hydrogen toy model & limitations to the node theorem
I'm working my way through a toy model just to improve my practical understanding of Sturm-Liouville ode theory and to get better at teaching quantum mechanics, but I ran into something strange that I want more info on. To set up, the toy model is a one-dimensional Hydrogen atom with the proton at the origin. So, we have an attractive Coulomb potential\begin{align} U(x)=-\dfrac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|x|}\end{align}
and so the time-independent Schrödinger equation takes the usual form
\begin{align} -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}-\dfrac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0|x|}\psi(x)=E\psi(x)\end{align}
Anticipating that the Bohr radius $a_0=\dfrac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{mq^2}$ will come in as a natural size scale and the Rydberg energy $R=\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2ma_0^2}$ as a natural energy scale, the substitutions $x=a_0 y$ and $\lambda=\dfrac{E}{R}$ transform the Schrödinger equation into the form
\begin{align}\dfrac{d^2\psi(y)}{dy^2}+\dfrac{2}{|y|}\psi(y)+\lambda \psi(y)=0 \end{align}
Without even solving this equation yet, I'll go through the following simple argument: Assuming that the bound-state eigenfunction solutions $\psi_n$ are twice differentiable and bounded, the Schrödinger equation immediately implies that
\begin{align}|\psi(y)|=|y|\left|\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d^2\psi(y)}{dy^2}+\dfrac{\lambda}{2}\psi(y)\right|\leq \left|\sup\dfrac{d^2\psi(y)}{dy^2} +\lambda \sup\psi(y)\right||y|\end{align} which means $\psi(y)=\mathcal{O}(y)$ as $y\to 0$. By continuity, for every eigenstate $\psi_n$, we then know that $\boxed{\psi_n(0)=0}$
Anyone familiar with the node theorem from basic quantum mechanics should see the red flag here. The node theorem states that the ground state of the one-dimensional Schrödinger equation should have zero nodes.
Moreover, for bound states, we want $\lambda =-k^2$ for some $k$. Asymptotically, we can see that, as $|y|\to \infty$, we need \begin{align}\dfrac{d^2\psi(y)}{dy^2}-k^2\psi(y)\sim 0\Rightarrow \psi(y)\sim e^{-k|y|} \end{align}
Substituting $\psi(y)=u(y)e^{-k|y|}$ into the Schrödinger equation transforms it to an equation for $u$ that looks like \begin{align} \dfrac{d^2 u}{dy^2} -2k\text{sgn}(y)\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{2}{|y|}u=0 \end{align} Expecting that the energy eigenvalues are the same as for the full Hydrogen atom, we could guess that $k_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$ which gives
\begin{align} \dfrac{d^2 u}{dy^2} -\dfrac{2\text{sgn}(y)}{n}\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{2}{|y|}u=0 \end{align} It is then relatively straightforward to show than an odd-parity $n$th degree polynomial solves this equation whose coefficients satisfy a nice recurrence relation. The normalized ground state can be readily found to be $\boxed{\psi_1(y)=\sqrt{2}ye^{-|y|}}$
I found this to be all quite beautiful and intuitively pleasing, as the probability density must go to zero near the origin by the uncertainty principle. But based on the node theorem, the ground state shouldn't have any nodes at all, which confuses me.
After working this out, I later found this resource that confirms these solutions, but also claims that the one-dimension Hydrogen atom is apparently an unpleasant probelm. The eigenfunctions only being odd-parity is problematic for building arbitrary states from the eigenspace. Though I don't really see that as an issue since this is just a pedagogical toy model.
So, my two primary questions are:

Is the node theorem violated for certain potentials? Most proofs seem to assume that $V(x)\ge 0$ and is nice in a certain sense, such as being continuous. The Coulomb potential clearly violates these assumptions. Moreover, I don't think the ground state should be nodeless at the origin according to the uncertainty principle which alone predicts that the electron should tend to keep at least some nonzero distance from the nucleus.

What exactly is so ugly about this model? It has basically every nice feature I was hoping to see. A large volume of literature seems to exist on this problem, but most of it concludes that the basic model is unacceptable.



"Expecting that the energy eigenvalues are the same as for the full Hydrogen atom." Why do you expect that? I could be wrong, but I'd actually expect the opposite - that the spectrum would be completely different from the 3d case. Is it true?

Another question "I don't think the ground state should be nodeless at the origin according to the uncertainty principle which alone predicts that the electron should tend to keep at least some nonzero distance from the nucleus." How does the uncertainty principle suggest this? The groundstate for normal hydrogen has a nonzero amplitude at the nucleus, and there's absolutely no issue with the uncertainty principle.

see Moss, R. E. "The hydrogen atom in one dimension." American Journal of Physics 55.5 (1987): 397-401.

@AXensen One, the literature seems to agree that the spectrum has the same eigenvalues for energy as the full 3-D model. The solutions also seem to suggest this. The physical reason why I expected this is, in the full 3-D model, the energy is independent of all quantum numbers except n.

@AXensen Two, this is a back-of-the-envelope estimate: if you confine the electron in Hydrogen to a box of width comparable to the Bohr radius, its energy will be of order a few eV, as expected from the Rydberg energy.
If you get it an order of magnitude closer, or god forbid a few dozen femtometers, the uncertainty in momentum brings the kinetic energy high enough to knock it out of the atom. The uncertainty principle thus predicts the electron cannot hang out too close to the nuclues. This is good: classical electromagnetism predicts atomic instability. Quantum theory prevents this.

@AXensen I probably should've also mentioned, you said, "the groundstate for normal hydrogen has a nonzero amplitude at the nucleus."
That is true, but the probability must be found by taking the wave function squared multiplied by the Jacobian, which gives an additional factor of the radius squared (and a sine of the latitude angle). That brings the probability for finding the electron in a spherical shell of radius r down to zero as r goes to zero.

I don't have an answer, but I do remember that this system is highly controversial. It was treated by like a dozen authors over the decades (from the 60s to present day), and they all arrived to different and contradicting conclusions about the parities and nodes of the allowed solutions...

@AXensen Actually, the $1/n^2$ dependence is already suggested by Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization. For a power law potential
$$
V(x)\sim\text{sgn}(\alpha)|x|^\alpha \ ,
$$
the energy (at least in the large $n$ limit) is always
$$
E_n\sim n^{\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha+2}} \ .
$$

@dennismoore94 Thanks for the responses. You are right about the 1/n^2. I see some argument with the uncertainty principle, but I don't think it leads to your conclusion. If the electron is within some radius $r$, the expectation value of kinetic energy is $\hbar^2/2mr^2$. The expectation value of potential energy is $e^2/4\pi\epsilon_0 r$. So the groundstate cannot have an $r$ much smaller than $h^2\epsilon_0/2me^2$. This says nothing about the probability at the nucleus being lower than elsewhere. The groundstate is free to have some smooth zero-free probability distribution with that scale.

@AXensen I'm not the OP, I just made a remark about the $n$-dependence :-D

@dennismoore94 oh. right. well thanks to both of you.

Related questions: Solution of 1D Schrodinger equation for the potential $V(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|}$, Why doesn't a quantum particle in an attractive 1D potential accumulate at the center?, Solutions for an electron near a 1D Coulomb.

@dennismoore94 Thank you for those resources. It seems from Trimok's response to that first post you linked to, the eigenfunctions are doubly degenerate at each energy level thanks to the Hamiltonian commuting with the parity operator. But that means you should be able to just flip the parity of each solution between even and odd, which implies that superpositions of them whose support is only on the left half or right half of the real line exist as a basis for state space, which he calls $u^+$ and $u^-$ in his response post. That is peculiar, but it seems to explain the odd-parity problem.

@dennismoore94 Also, from reading other forums on the differentiability of the wave function, it seems the Coulomb potential $-1/|x|$ is the main culprit for the node number being different than the one-dimensional node theorem would predict. This also seems to mess with the eigenspace sufficiently to allow for a basis consisting of eigenfunctions which are not necessarily smooth at the origin.

I can't really do justice to this, but I'm not sure that the even parity solutions of Loudon are valid. He basically uses $rR_{n0}(r)$ and the $l=0$ radial Schr. equation in 3D to identify solutions for $x>0$ and $x<0$, and then "glues" these together to form even/odd solutions. But for the even case, these "glued" solutions do not really solve the equation at $x=0$. You can check this for $|x|\exp(-|x|)$ by plugging it into the equation, and using $|x|'=\text{sgn}(x)$ and $|x|''=2\delta(x)$. But even...

...without this issue, the solutions would not form a complete set of states, because the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below, and all "solutions" which are non-zero at $x=0$ collapse to $-\infty$. This means that if you want to use these states in further calculations, none of the resolution-of-identity tricks will work that we are so used to in QM.

@dennismoore94 I was under the assumption that the even-parity solutions solved the Schrödinger equation in the weak sense for the self-adjoint extension of the Hamiltonian, though I didn't go through and work out the details of that. However, suppose we did assume that the state space consists only of square-integrable states that do vanish at the origin. Would the set of odd-parity and even-parity eigenstates taken together still not provide an eigenbasis for that state space?
